# " 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable" in my machine learning code

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I want to plot the learning curves for two ml models with a function.

```
def Learning_Curves(estimator,data1=input_data,data2=output_data,cv=5,train_sizes=train_sizes):
    train_sizes,train_score,validation_score=learning_curve(estimator,data1,data2,cv=cv,train_sizes=train_sizes,shuffle=True)
    mean_train_score=-train_score.mean(axis=1)
    mean_validation_score=-validation_score(axis=1)
    sns.lineplot(train_sizes,mean_train_score)
    sns.lineplot(train_sizes,mean_validation_score)
    plt.ylim(0,40)

plt.figure(figsize = (16,5))   
for model,i in zip([LinearRegression(),RandomForestRegressor()],[1,2]):                 
    plt.subplot(1,2,i)
    Learning_Curves(model)
```

cant understand what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to forget calling `validation_score.mean` here:

> `mean_validation_score = -validation_score(axis=1)`

Also you can replace this line:

```
for model,i in zip([LinearRegression(),RandomForestRegressor()],[1,2]):
```

with this

```
for i, model in enumerate((LinearRegression(),RandomForestRegressor()), start=1):
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time. i was just a silly mistake sry.